# How to color some numbers in Excel cell using python or R

Tags: r, excel, xlsx

I have this example of Excel file where the data contain some random values. I generated this using `RAND()` function.

What I want to do is read this excel file using R so that I can color red and bold the number `9` wherever it appears in the cell. Is this possible to do?

I've been searching on Google a while but haven't been able to figure it out any other way other than using VBA. But it's not an option.

Does anybody have an example of how to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Do you only want to bold the digit 9 when it appears or bold the enitere cell if 9 appears in it?

Comment: Just bold 9 when it appears - not the whole cell.

Comment: I can't find anything in R that will format individual characters in a cell, most packages format by applying styles to cells/ranges. Why is VBA not an option?

Comment: @nori, thanks for checking. I couldn’t either. Do you know if it’s possible to insert shape in cells using R instead. That way if I find a 9, I can add some kind of shape.

Comment: @norie, VBA is not an option because our organization doesn't allow Macros to run on our PC. This is why I'm writing everything on python. I found out that python's openpyxl doesn't let me do what I want, but found a google group discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/g/r-package-xlsx/c/z2OH0fWmBtY?pli=1) where someone did but couldn't figure out how. That method didn't work for me, so was thinking maybe there's a way to modify formatting for individual characters now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I wanted to do is not possible using any of the python packages - `xlsxwriter` can only do rich text like I wanted but only on new cell but cannot modify, `openpyxl` can do a lot of things but not rich text. Wasn't sure if it could be done using R or not, but seems like it's not possible to do what I want done. I saw a Google Group discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/g/r-package-xlsx/c/z2OH0fWmBtY?pli=1) where they showed a potential method to perform what I wanted, but that method didn't work for me. It showed `.jnew` is not recognized.

So, instead, what I did is created a function to add a color dot (image) to the cell to delineate that the cell contains the value I'm searching for - 9 in this case. The reason I can't use conditional formatting is because there's another conditional formatting that is applied for another logic.

```
def __add_color_dots__(self, ws=None, excel_filename=None):
   
    from openpyxl.drawing.image import Image
    import os

    path = os.path.abspath('blue-dot.png')
    image = Image(path)

    image.anchor = 'C4'

    ws.add_image(image)

    return ws
```

Hope this will help someone later and that this method maybe a useful workaround.

Comment: Doesn't the 'dot' apply to the cell rather than the digit? Also, why would existing conditional formatting preclude you from applying further conditional formatting?

Comment: @norie, if I have multiple colored dots, then I can differentiate which color belongs to which number. Say, if 9 = blue dot, and 3 = green dot, 5 = red dot. Then, I can add those 3 dots in the cell individually for users to see and find what they're looking for. If I use conditional formatting for 9, and then 3, the formatting for 9 will be overwritten by formatting for 3. I was going to use those color coding and font face for each value we need.